# flux/fluidcontent and css_styled_content maipulation

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

TYPO3 v6.2: I need to manipulate content via css_styled_content within a grid created with Flux. But Flux/Fluidcontent takes some kind of default settings from css_styled_content and ignores my overrides in total (even if I change it directly in the css_styled_contennt extension).

How can I get into the Flux/Fluidcontent css_styled_content settings to manipulate them via TS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "manipulate content via css_styled_content"? What exactly are you trying to do? Please specify what you want to achieve and what you tried so far.

Comment: For example: I have a grid created by flux. Within the grid is a standard textpic (text with images) element. There I just want to get rid of all wrappings. That's mostly it. I just want to manipulate or adjust css_styled_content settings for standard content elements within a flux grid.

I already tried the standard way of overriding tt_content.image.20.xyz. Even if I try to override those settings within the extension itself (in the static folder) it is not working (and yes, I cleared the caches).